# SQL Size comparison

Tags: union, sql

I have a database where I check on the size, because clients may only use a certain amount of space, aswell as they may only have a certain number of 'pages', which I put in the db aswell.

I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT table_schema "Servers",
sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 "Data Base Size in MB",
sum( data_free )/ 1024 / 1024 "Free Space in MB"
FROM information_schema.TABLES
GROUP BY table_schema ;
```

This returns a table with the information I need. However, I would like to add 3 coloumns that also show how much each user is using. First I tried like this:

```
SELECT table_schema "Servers",
sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 "Data Base Size in MB",
sum( data_free )/ 1024 / 1024 "Free Space in MB",
property_value "MaxWebhotelSize"
FROM information_schema.TABLES, properties
WHERE property_key LIKE 'MaxWEbhotelSize'
GROUP BY table_schema
UNION
SELECT property_value "MaxPages"
FROM properties
WHERE property_key LIKE 'MaxPages';
```

This should take add two of the coloumns that I need. If I leave out everything from union and down it works well and adds information about maximum webhotel size to the table, but when I try to add another coloumn I get an error saying "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns". I tried some other ways around it, but can't seem to figure out a good way where I get the right results. I'm quite new to SQL, sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

In a union query, the number of columns should be equal.

So, if you have 3 columns in the first section of your union query, you should also have 3 columns in the second.

In your example, you only have 1 column in the second section. Please specify what you require in the additional 2 columns, and we might be able to assist with the query.

Comment: Well, not sure how to express it. But here goes:
I have several MySQL Databases. Each db with many tables, one of these tables has the name "properties" in which allowed size is written, max amount of pages and max amount of mails.
The query should check size on all tables on one db, and give back the size it is using. I think that part is working. To this new table I need to add or append these 3 max values to the new table which holds servername, used size and free space.